# Reformat output to one line per interval of a command in batch mode

Tags: unix, monitoring, perf

I am using `perf stat` to log some hardware counters, it has a batch mode in which it prints the counter values every 1s (or whatever the interval). I want the output of one interval in one single line instead of multiple lines as shown below:

```
#           time             counts events
     1.000650887        4015.442880 task-clock (msec)         [100.00%]
     1.000650887                214 context-switches          [100.00%]
     1.000650887                  2 cpu-migrations            [100.00%]
     1.000650887                 14 page-faults
     1.000650887         58,447,833 cycles                    [83.19%]
     1.000650887         50,476,562 stalled-cycles-frontend   [83.26%]
     1.000650887         18,469,093 stalled-cycles-backend    [66.85%]
     1.000650887         13,861,731 instructions              [83.56%]
     1.000650887          3,963,967 branches                  [83.60%]
     1.000650887            180,104 branch-misses             [83.21%]
     2.004854486        4003.706096 task-clock (msec)
     2.004854486                245 context-switches
     2.004854486                  0 cpu-migrations
     2.004854486                 30 page-faults
     2.004854486         60,750,234 cycles                    [83.27%]
     2.004854486         38,491,129 stalled-cycles-frontend   [83.26%]
     2.004854486         20,561,260 stalled-cycles-backend    [66.95%]
     2.004854486         15,651,369 instructions              [83.36%]
     2.004854486          3,826,936 branches                  [83.25%]
     2.004854486            183,319 branch-misses             [83.27%]
```

So that it can be saved as a `csv` file with each counter value for one interval as a single row. Is there a simple way to do this?

something like:

```
task-clock, context-switches, page-faults, cycles, instructions, branches
4105, 214, 14, 58447833, 13861, 3963967
4003, 245, 30, 60750234, 15651369, 3826936
```

my perf version is: 3.13.11.10

Comment: Can you show the desired output based on the input above?

Comment: Edited. Ideally, I would like to reformat the output at run-time of the perf stat command so that I can directly save it as a csv file and also use it to calculate some other quantities such as instructions per cycle. But if that is not possible then a post-processing solution will also be fine.

Comment: No. It is not possible without any post-processing. `perf` can output only the above format or `csv`-like using `-x` switch, but it is still rows-oriented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pass the output of `perf stat` through something like

```
awk '/task-clock/{printf("%d ", $2);} /page-faults/{printf("%d ", $2);} /branch-misses/{printf("%d\n", $2);} '
```

I did not add here all the fields and the header. The additions are pretty obvious

Comment: This a post processing solution after the output has been saved to file. Is there a way to do it at run-time? Or is it not possible at all?

Comment: It is not a post processing. You can run it as `perf stat | awk ....`. Just add `BEGIN {print "task  page branch\n";}  ` to the `awk` program get the headers

Comment: I don't think it works, can you try executing it and test?

Comment: I made a small script printing your output and run it through my `awk`. It worked

Comment: One more thing. You should remove commas from the output if you would like to print using the `'%d'` format. I did the following: `| tr -d ',' | awk 'BEGIN {print "task  page branch\n"; i = 0;} /task-clock/{printf("%d ", $2);} /page-faults/{printf("%d ", $2);} /branch-misses/{printf("%d %d\n", $2, i++);}`